# Proving that K is an involutary key

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

let's suppose that k=(α,β) in a Afffine Cypher on Z26
**Prove** that k is an involutary key **iff**
n | (a^2 -1) & β(α+1) is congruent to 0 (mod n)

I know that an involutary key is a key where
the encryption function and
decryption function is equal but I have no idea how I can use that to show that
n | (a^2 - 1) and that β(α+1) is congruent to 0 (mod n)

I'm hopefully lost.. I'm not even sure how they got to the end statement to begin with. If i set ek(x) = dk(x) I don't get anywhere close to what I need to prove.

Comment: Also, you've written $n$, but that must mean 26.  (Or, your problem is supposed to be on a generic affine cipher, and not mod 26.)

Comment: Most likely the word is "involutary", as in related to an involution.  Since this is a very obscure technical word, most systems will mark this as a spelling error and try to correct it to "involuntary" with an extra n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you half of this problem.  All algebra is occurring mod $26$ (or $n$, whatever you like). If encryption occurs by $e(x) = \alpha x + \beta$ then decryption occurs by $d(x) = \alpha^{-1}x - \alpha^{-1}\beta$.  This you already know, as $d$ is just $e^{-1}$ and you can do that algebra.

Your problem is asking for $d=e$, so equate the coefficients and get to work:
$$
\alpha = \alpha^{-1} \quad \text{ and } \quad \beta = -\alpha^{-1}\beta.
$$

Comment: I'm so sorry I equate them and I still don't see how you get $$
\alpha = \alpha^{-1} \quad \text{ and } \quad \beta = -\alpha^{-1}\beta.
$$

Comment: They are both functions of the form $f(x) = rx + s$.  Two such things are equal if and only if (a) the coefficients on $x$ are equal and (b) the constant terms are equal.  I'm just equating the coefficients in $e(x)$ and $d(x)$.

Comment: I see it now, thank you